# Issue in installing ng2-bootstrap in my Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been trying to add ng-bootstrap in my Angular 2 application for drop down. I am getting following error in console. 
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkWeV.png)

the following are my System.config.js code,
[System.config.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP2nB.png)

Can any one please explain how should I install and use ng2-bootstrap. Thanks.

Updated my system.config.js code,

```js
/**
 * WEB ANGULAR VERSION
 * (based on systemjs.config.js in angular.io)
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      // Complete copy of compiler options in standard tsconfig.json
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "typeRoots": [
        "../../node_modules/@types/"
      ]
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common@2.2.1/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@2.2.1/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@2.2.1/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms@2.2.1/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http@2.2.1/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http@2.2.1/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.2.1/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.2.1/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router@3.2.1/bundles/router.umd.js',
        'ng2-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs@5.0.0-rc.3',
      'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript':                'npm:typescript@2.0.3/lib/typescript.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts',        
      },
    // ng2-bootstrap
     'ng2-bootstrap':              { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });

  if (!global.noBootstrap) { bootstrap(); }

  // Bootstrap the `AppModule`(skip the `app/main.ts` that normally does this)
  function bootstrap() {

    // Stub out `app/main.ts` so System.import('app') doesn't fail if called in the index.html
    System.set(System.normalizeSync('app/main.ts'), System.newModule({ }));

    // bootstrap and launch the app (equivalent to standard main.ts)
    Promise.all([
      System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'),
      System.import('app/app.module')
    ])
    .then(function (imports) {
      var platform = imports[0];
      var app      = imports[1];
      platform.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(app.AppModule);
    })
    .catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
  }

})(this);
```

Comment: Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap

Comment: Yes, I have followed that one.

Comment: You say, you've followed the samples,  but your systemjs is different to them.

Comment: I have installed ng2- bootstrap using the comment " npm install ng2-bootstrap --save " after that checked my node modules, given the exact ng2-bootstrap path in system js " map ". Same way included in index.html also. same as they said.

Comment: can you share your code so that its easy to sort out

Comment: Yes , I have edited and added the system.config.js in my question.

Comment: Refer this [GIT_EXAMPLE](https://github.com/valor-software/angular2-quickstart)

Comment: In my project , its all same. I am downloading new one, from the link which you gave, installing and checking out.

Comment: Any breakthrough? @manjula

Comment: I got held up with other design works. Still in progress

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, there is a mistake in your packages section. You have added ng2-bootstrap inside app.

Update packages like this-

```
       // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    // ng2-bootstrap
    'moment': 'node_modules/moment',
    'ng2-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    // ng2-bootstrap
    'ng2-bootstrap':              { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'moment':                     { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

Comment: Hi, Yup I have changed the system.js as you mentioned . Still it did not work, I am getting an error like    "ng2-bootstrap.umd.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Output' of undefined
    at ng2-bootstrap.umd.min.js:4"